# The wifi connection on the phone is losing to other devices when connected

Tags: wi-fi, vivo

My Vivo T1 Pro was initially connected to WiFi, but when another device just connected to the WiFi connection, my connection to WiFi died and I couldn't connect again until the other device disconnected, how do I solve it?

Comment: There are multiple possibilities: the other device may be defect or simply violate the Wifi spec, it could be a Wifi router problem like too many Wifi devices connected, most Wifi router have a limit how many Wifi device can be connected at the same time, some can handle 30, other more than 200.

Comment: We need more details on your wifi, router, waps and mobile.